# Generating jQuery dialog buttons from an array of values

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm trying to dynamically create a jQuery UI dialog with buttons derived from the array passed to the function, and then pass the key of the selected button to the next function on the button click, however having no luck so far.

A simple test case:

```
var buttons = {};
for (var o in options) {
  buttons[options[o]]=function(){
    alert(o);
  }
}
```

The labels of the button are correct, however on click the alert() always displays the key of the last element in the buttons array.

I've tried different tricks (copying o to a local variable, etc.), but to no avail.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: can you show the example output?

Comment: Post the contents of `option` is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `o` is bound to the scope of the `foo` loop, meaning that when the alert gets called it retains the last value assigned to it.

As you're using jQuery, you can use `$.each` to solve this:

```
var buttons = {};
$.each(options, function(i, v) {
     buttons[v] = function() {
         alert(v);
     }
});
```

The `v` is equivalent to `options[o]` from your own code, but without being tied to the scope of a loop variable.